One source for different songs
I'm developing a client-server application that sends data in chunks from the server to each client. In turn, the client accepts this data and immediately passes it to rodio for playback. But when the client receives data that belongs to a new song and not the previous one, then rodio stops playing the data.
Why can't I use one source for different songs, and how can I fix that If I need that functionality?
Simple code example:
use std::{fs, io::Cursor};
fn main() {
    let (_stream, handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
    let sink = rodio::Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();

    let mut data = fs::read("guiro-sweep.mp3").unwrap();
    data.extend(fs::read("on_the_moon.mp3").unwrap());

    sink.append(rodio::Decoder::new(Cursor::new(data)).unwrap());

    sink.sleep_until_end();
}

When we run this program, we see that the first source play successfully, but when the second source should start playing, the program terminates.

Concatenating mp3 data of multiple files doesn't magically create a mp3 file of all of the songs.

@cafce25 so is there any way I can store the source data in one storage and play it with rodio?

Yes, you can slice it into individual chunks of mp3 data and create a Decoder for each chunk.
